# Dropdown/Select Box with just an arrow using HTML/JavaScript

Tags: jquery, html-select, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2, jquery-chosen

I need to create a dropdown widget with a minimal footprint - no box around it. It is activated by simply clicking on a small arrow. Here's the visual design for it:

[image]

Note how the selected item is displayed in large bold letters, while the dropdown list should be in normal text.

Any idea if such a control is available in open source? I looked at "Chosen" and "Select2", both very popular, but they have full-fledged chrome around them and don't know how easy to style. Any ideas welcome.

Comment: How about emulating a select box yourself with some javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any off-the-shelf control that met my requirements. I finally wrote one. It is based on the jQuery Widget Factory. It does not yet have any keyboard interaction or accessibility implemented yet, but it's a start. Here's the github project: https://github.com/archfirst/minimal-select. Please feel free to fork and contribute.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Fiddle:**http://jsfiddle.net/HNNRf/

HTML

```
<div class="styled-select">
    <select><option>Here is the first option</option><option>The second option</option></select>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 268px;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 34px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   }

.styled-select {
   width: 240px;
   height: 34px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url(new_arrow.png) no-repeat right #fff;
   }
```

Just change the image URL.

Comment: Difficult to make this work. Tried font-size: 36px and text starts cutting off. Changing line-height and height does not help much. Also the design calls for right justified text - adding text-align: right does not help and has different behavior on different browsers. I have a feeling making a native control look like this across browsers will be a challenge.